# tt_news RSS Feed, show HTMLcode

Tags: typo3, tt-news

i work at an RSS-Feed from the tt_news Extension. My Mainproblem is that the XML-File shows the HTML-Structure of my Website, but i don't know why?

Any Ideas?

Thats my Constantscode:

```
    # RSS2
plugin.tt_news {
  # SYS-Folder mit News
  pid_list               = 61
  # Seite mit Singleanzeige
  singlePid              = 62
  displayXML {
    xmlTitle             = {$c_rss.title}
    xmlLink              = {$baseURL}
    xmlFormat            = rss2
    rss2_tmplFile        = fileadmin/Resources/Private/Templates/rss_2.tmpl
    # Anzahl News in Reader
    xmlLimit             = 10
    xmlDesc              = {$c_rss.description}
    # Sprache
    xmlLang              = {$c_rss.lang}
    title_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    title_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.stripHtml = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.crop = 425 | ...
    subheader_stdWrap.ifEmpty.field = bodytext
    xmlLastBuildDate     = 1
    xmlIcon = main/typo3conf/ext/tt_news/ext_icon.gif
  }
}
```

And thats the TS-Code:

```
# RSS
page.headerData.1100 = TEXT
page.headerData.1100.value = <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS-Feed" href="{$baseURL}/rss.xml" />
xmlnews = PAGE
xmlnews {
  typeNum = 100
  10 >
  10 < plugin.tt_news
  10.pid_list >
  10.pid_list = 61
  10.singlePid = 63
  10.defaultCode = XML
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/xml
    no_cache = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: And how looks your url to this site? If your url looks like that www.something.com/rss.html the correct address for xml looks like that: www.somethin.com/rss/rss.xml (if you are using realurl ext)

Comment: I had similar problem two days ago, and the reason was some typo in rss template.

Comment: My link looks so: http://relaunch.smt-wertheim.de/home/rss.xml
Thats the Output :(
What do you mean with typo in rss Template?

Comment: Try to load standard `rss_2.tmpl` template without any modification. If it will be ok the reason is in template - it can be anything (.,;<> etc). If the output will be the same as now there is some problem in TypoScript.

Comment: I use the standard template :(

Comment: and TypoScript is also standard?

Comment: Great that you solved it. The way tt_news has to be configured to create an rss feed is really weird (and oldschool). tx_news does a much better job here, as there's a fluid template for the feed that can be formed freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy with this constans:

```
### News settings ###
plugin.tt_news {
   displayXML {
    xmlCaching = 1
    xmlLimit = 15
    xmlFormat = rss2
    xmlTitle = News
    xmlLink = http://your.url/
    xmlDesc = description
    xmlLang = de
    title_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    title_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.stripHtml = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
    subheader_stdWrap.crop = 425 | ... | 1
    subheader_stdWrap.ifEmpty.field = bodytext
    xmlLastBuildDate = 1
    rss2_tmplFile = fileadmin/Resources/Private/Templates/rss_2.tmpl
   }
}
```

Comment: it works! i have a problem in my other tt_news file. Thank you so much :)